# How to pass a file path out of Python into windows command prompt without escaping issues?

Tags: python

I am trying to set up a subprocess call to bcp, but am running into an issue with windows file paths using backslashes.

In python, a backslash is escaped by another backslash and that works fine in most circumstances.

However, since the command prompt expects a file path to use a single \
and python is passing it \\ , the command will fail.

As I am concatenating the command from multiple arguments (I need a path to the source file, format file and log file), it doesn't seem possible to do those joins without Python inserting the extra escape character.

Even os.join will store the string it creates with escape characters.

Is it possible to make windows ignore the extra backslashes or to remove them programatically?

Here's the code in question:

```
datacommand = ('bcp.exe ' + table_path + ' in ' + file_path 
                   + " -f " + format_path + " -e " + log_path + " -S "
                   + self.server + instance
                   + " -T -q -t" + sep + " -F" + str(int(header) + 1))
subprocess.call(datacommand)
```

The call is constructed in a member function of a PYODBC wrapper I have, though that's more for logical organization than being contingent on class methods or variables.

The various paths aren't hardcoded but generated further up the function.

If I print the string in the shell and copy-paste it into a command prompt it works perfectly, as the print removes the extra escape characters.

Comment: How are you generating your command line?  Python won't double the backslashes unless you're printing the `__repr__` value.

Comment: you can try use letter r before your string path.

Comment: Is it possible to force a string to be interpreted as raw after it's been created?

Comment: Windows makes this class of problem hard to comprehensively solve, because it lets each program implement its own command-line parser; so just because Program A parses escape characters in a specific way doesn't mean Program B will do the same thing. There's a standard/default parser bundled with the libc, but not every program uses it.

Comment: That said -- doubled-up backslashes in Python aren't actually a problem, because they're just part of how Python _prints_ the string when it's building a representation of it; they're not actually part of the string's contents.

Comment: So if, for example, `print(len('\\'))` returns `1` -- that means that that `'\\'` string is actually only one backslash, and it'll be passed around that way (as one character, not two) to any external process unless you actively go out of your way to make Python convert it to a `repr()`esentation.

Comment: Is there some way to "close" a subprocess call that I'm missing? It sounds like it should work in theory but it makes the shell freeze up and the script doesn't progress past the subprocess call when I run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Charles Duffy for the detailed breakdown.

As it turns out, the issue was that using subprocess.call from a python script causes hanging since it waits for the command to return something, and in the case of BCP, there is no return.

Solution is to use:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(command) 
process.terminate()
```